# How to pick value from ng-options based on data (on load)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

when user expand object detail he get data about this object. To be more specific it is array of objects. Each object of this array looks like:

```
{
  id:"6c8b7b19-17e1-4d2b-b47b-ad2c3f2e967b",
  name:"TERM-xx",
  overchargeTolerance:2,
  pricingMethod:"ALTERNATIVE_MIN",
  ratioGlassToAccessory:2,
  ratioReplaceToRepair:2,
  validFrom:"2016-02-02T08:55:22",
  validTo:"2016-09-02T08:55:22",
  vatRate:2
}
```

As mentioned above its array of objects so I ng-repeat over it:

```
<div class="row admin-sub-form" ng-show="isToogled(node.id)" ng-repeat="term in glassTerms">
```

And then insert values to inputs. But because sometimes value is constance from backend I cant let user write there anything so I offer selectbox with ng-options as below

```
        <select id="pricingMethod"
                class="form-control"
                ng-model="term.pricingMethod"
                ng-options="o as o for o in pricingMethod"
        >
        </select>
```

What I want:

When user load page it should pick from selectbox correct value automaticly. Right now it just display selectbox with possiblity to pick any value but doesnt pick anything. I have to click and pick it manualy.

p.s. If I replace selectbox with simple input as:

```
<input ng-model="term.pricingMethod" id="pricingMethod" class="form-control"/>
```

Value in that input is correctly displayed, in this case ALTERNATIVE_MIN

Any idea?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for it? and also show the pricingMethod array. And you check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/keyurshah24/5kpxzrgf/) also

Answer (score 0):

```
 $scope.term.pricingMethod = 1;  //replace 1 with the value which u want to display by default
```

> for example if you have this list

```
[
        {"name":"option 1","id": 1},
        {"name":"option 2","id": 2},
        {"name":"option 3","id": 3}
    ];
```

> and you want to load "option 2" on page load, then set the model with the value 2 like this

```
$scope.term.pricingMethod = 2;
```